# How to copy objects

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, xml-deserialization

I was trying to create copy of objects in **silverligth 5** where interfaces like IFormatters and IcCloanble do not support.
*

My objects are like this: (Note that these obkjects are obtained on deserializing xml):
I tried to do copy like this:

```
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "component")]
        public class Component
        {
            [XmlElement("attributes")]
            public Attributes Attributes { get; set; } 

            [XmlIgnore]
            public Attributes atrbtOrginal = new Attributes();
            [XmlIgnore]
            public Attributes atrbtCopy{ get; set; }
        }
        public Component()
            {          
                atrbtCopy= atrbtOrginal ;
            } 
Sure it will not work then i got this code on seraching on Google :

 public static class ObjectCopier
    {
        public static T Clone<T>(T source)
        {
            if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
            }

            // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
            using (stream)
            {
                formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
                stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }

    }
```

And i thought of doing something liek this:

```
objectOrginal.Clone();.
```

But the problem in silverligth5 is :

```
Error   2   The type or namespace name 'BinaryFormatter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'IFormatter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Even if i do something like this.It still do not work :

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
public static class ObjectCopier
    {
        public static Attributes DeepCopy(this Attributes oSource)
        {
            Attributes oClone;
            DataContractSerializer dcs = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                dcs.WriteObject(ms, oSource);
                ms.Position = 0;
                oClone = (Attributes)dcs.ReadObject(ms);
            }
            return oClone;
        }

    }
```

is there any alternative in Silverlight 5 . Please explain in detail.
Thanks a lot.

In this case the problem is : (even i have included `System.Runtime.Serialization`)

```
Error   5   The type or namespace name 'DataContractSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error   6   The type or namespace name 'DataContractSerializer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions. You've already posted this question once.

Comment: @ChrisMantle but that answer is not supported in Silverlight. Could you please help me ?